# Python Pandas datetime64[ns] comparision

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to use indexing to select rows in my dataframe after the date 2011-01-01. I used following line of code to return only part of dataframe that is after 2011-01-01

```
  df = df[df.Date > np.datetime64('2011-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

I don't get an error. However, I only see dates that are of 2016 year nothing on 2011. When I manually open file I can see that there are plenty of entries starting with 2011 year.

What do I do wrong here? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here is a sniped of data:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhEa3.jpg)

Comment: Please share a snippet of the data in `df`; preferably rows including dates before and after `2011-01-01`.

Comment: I just edited my post to include snippet of data. It is a long dataset and date are not consistent. I noticed that when I apply .sort_index on my dataframe I still see only results for 2016 at the head and the tail of the data frame.

Comment: I cannot use the picture to test your code. It should be data that anyone here can copy and paste in their python consoles to test your code.Try using [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to paste the data there and share the link subsequently.

Comment: I used filedropper here is the link http://www.filedropper.com/crimes-2001topresent_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing your data, it looks like all the values of the `Date` column are still there, even after filtering. It's just that your data is too large to be displayed fully on your console (take a look at [pandas settings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)). Therefore some of it is being (visually) truncated to fit the page.

The trick to use convert the `Date` column to a pandas datetime object and handle the filtering from there:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv', header = 0)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

filterer = df.Date > pd.to_datetime('2011-01-01 00:00:00')
df = df[filterer]
```

Now when you look at the 200th row in the `Date` column, you should get something:

```
df['Date'].iloc[200]
#Timestamp('2011-05-31 19:30:00')
```

At row 2000 in column `Date`:

```
df['Date'].iloc[2000]
#Timestamp('2013-09-19 20:45:00')
```

In essence, everything is there. Your console is perhaps too small to fit it all.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Abdou! I thought that data for 2011 maybe somewhere in the middle of filtered data. I got frustrated when I used sort_index and didn't see it. This is the code I used to sort: 
**df = df.sort_index(axis=0)**

Comment: You should have used `df.sort_values(by = 'Date')` since `Date` is a column, and not the index.